# Bootstrap Basic

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am new to bootstrap and I very much confused with this basic situation and I feel like I couldn't move forward without understanding the grid system.

Question 1: How would I know the equivalent class prefix of a certain device to another device.Example: col-md-6 what is its equivalent if i wanna show it to smaller devices, what will be the col-sm-X or col-xs-X? I am really confused with griding system.

Question 2: I came across with a bootstrap tutorials. And I am confuse why did he place col-sm-10 in the stores-banners in which it only takes 6 colums in 960 grid, why isn't it col-sm-6 instead? please see image attached.

In following image I'm referring to the buttons area
[image]

```
<div class="container top-description-app">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 top-description-text">
                <h1>Hello</h1>
                <h3>We take mobile photography to a brand new level.</h3>
                <p>With our free app you can take amazing photos straigh your phone.</p>
                <div class="col-sm-10 stores-banners">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Get the free app</a>
                    </br>
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/apple-banner.png" alt="App Store"></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/google-banner.png" alt="Google Store"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 top-iphone-wrapper">                   
                <img src="img/iphone-header.png" alt="iPhone app">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope you can help me guyx. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends how wide you want the div and what percentage of the screen you want it to take up, 6 times 6 probably adds up to 100%, col-sm-10 times 6 would add up to a smaller than 100% I am guessing.

Answer (score 1):

1. It depends on how you want your website to look like on different screen sizes.

Basically, `xs` - mobile, `sm` - tablets, `md` - desktops, `lg` - large desktops.

Example:

```css
p {
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12"><p></p></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12"><p></p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code means you will have: 1 columns on mobiles (xs), 2 columns on tabletes (sm) and 1 column on desktops (md) and large desktops (lg).

2. This code you provided isn't really correct. If you nest `col-` classes inside another `col-` class you should create another row.

```
<div class="container top-description-app">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 top-description-text">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <h3>We take mobile photography to a brand new level.</h3>
      <p>With our free app you can take amazing photos straigh your phone.</p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 stores-banners">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Get the free app</a>
          </br>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/apple-banner.png" alt="App Store"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/google-banner.png" alt="Google Store"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 top-iphone-wrapper">
      <img src="img/iphone-header.png" alt="iPhone app">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this code means that you will have `col-sm-10` inside this `col-sm-6` class (so 10 of 12 columns occupies this `col-sm-6` column).

Example:

```css
p {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 150px;
}
span {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>Column</p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <span>Column in another column</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <span>Column in another column</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>Column</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> col-md-6 what is its equivalent

there's no equivalent, I mean you shouldn't look at it like that, each bootstrap grid divides your screen into 12 equal columns. we have 4 screen sizes in bootstrap called `lg` or large, `md` or medium, `sm` or small and `xs` or extra-small. your column definition should be based on what you wanna show to the user at that screen size.

Take a look at **[this example](http://codepen.io/Amin52J/pen/yJbwoj)**  to better understand the concept. try resizing the screen to see the columns in action.

And for your second question, let me explain it with an example:

Imagine you have a screen with the width `1200px` and you wanna have a column with the width `500px` how do you do that using the bootstrap grid system? you need to bring your box (screen) size to `1000px` and divide it in two. how do you do that?

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it is that simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses a 12 by 12 grid system, and you have grids within grids.

In your example above, the screen is split with two `col-sm-6`, on all devices with a screen width larger than the sm breakpoint (which defaults to around 768px, but is customizable), and to stack on devices smaller than the sm breakpoint.

You also asked about the `col-sm-10` element, which is INSIDE `the col-sm-6` element, which makes a container that is 10/12th the width of half the screen (or half the `col-sm-6` that is its parent).

I would have wrapped that `col-sm-10` in a `<div class="row">`, and added an empty `<div class="col-sm-2"></div>` to finish out the row. That would say for screens smaller than sm, take up the whole space, and screens larger than sm, take up 10/12ths of the space available (which in this case is half the screen, because of the element it is nested in).

If you wanted to always make sure those buttons were never quite as wide as the text above: if you wanted the right edge of the buttons to be set in, you might make the `col-sm-10` and `col-sm-2` like `col-xs-10`, which says NEVER stack these divs, regardless of screen size.